# External javascript hijacks console.log

Tags: javascript

I noticed a strange behavior whereby my `console.log` statements weren't doing anything. I finally tracked this to an external script:

```
<!-- Load the systems bio heatmap package -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://systemsbiology-visualizations.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/js/load.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
//  uncommenting the following line ruins console.log
//    systemsbiology.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["bioheatmap"]});
  </script>
```

Unfortunately this script is used to run the only heatmap package for google charts (AFAIK).

Is there a way to somehow backup `console.log` and then restore it after executing their code? I tried doing a shallow backup but had no luck:

```
<!-- Load the systems bio heatmap package -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://systemsbiology-visualizations.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/js/load.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var temp = console.log;
//  the following line ruins console.log
systemsbiology.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["bioheatmap"]});

console.log = temp;
console.log('test'); // does not work

  </script>
```

Now I'm asking someone who knows what he's doing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where is your attempt of the "shallow backup but had no luck"? I'm sure there's an easier way of this, but you could do: `var logger = console.log.bind(console);` before the bad part, then use `console.log = logger;` to restore it maybe?

Comment: I'd open a bug for the project. [B]ioheatmap.js, line 682 turns it off if firebug is not present. This ignores other browsers like Chrome.

Comment: *"does not work"* means what exactly?

Comment: @FelixKling in this case I believe "does not work" means `TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: @gpojd +1 Good find. At least I can grab my own local version of the file and comment out their "helping" code. Free code from the web... worth every penny.

Answer (score 4):

Your code *does work* but only if the `console` object is preserved, and the methods on it are replaced.

```
var temp = console.log;

//  the following line ruins console.log
console.log = function() {};

// put console.log back
console.log = temp;
console.log('test');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CBv2T/

If instead the `console` object is replaced, as I suspect is the case, this won't work.  So why not save/restore the whole console object?

```
var temp = console;

//  the following line ruins console.log
window.console = {};

// Put the whole console object back
window.console = temp;
console.log('test');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CBv2T/1/

---

But as @gpojd notes, this is a major bug in the library you are using.  They should really fix that...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- backup console log method -->
  <script> var temp = console.log.bind(console); </script>

<!-- Load the systems bio heatmap package -->
  <script src="http://systemsbiology-visualizations.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/js/load.js"></script>

<!-- restore  console log method -->
  <script>
     console.log = temp;
     console.log('test'); // does work
  </script>
```

EDIT: you can likely fix the code in the OP using bind:

```
  var temp = console.log.bind(console);
```

since the log() method is hard-coded to use "this" internally, we need to take "this" with us when we memorize the method.

Comment: This shallow copy works stochastically and only for `console.log('test')` (due to race conditions, where the systemsbio code has not executed yet). Later console statements don't work.

Comment: They don't show up. Please see answer above (it is described as a bug in the library).

Comment: "don't show up" is kinda vauge, but it's probably an illegal invocation that's breaking the method, see my updated answer for that fix...